# uninitialised value and clang optimizations

Tags: c, optimization, stack, clang, allocation

I have created a program to print "Hello World" string as bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void callString(char *_string);
int main() 
{
    char *myString;

// Allocating memory
    myString = (char *)malloc(
      (unsigned long)strlen(myString)
      * sizeof(char)
    );

    myString = "Hello World!";
    callString(myString);

    // should I free(myString) here?

    return 0;
}

static void 
callString(char *_string) 
{ 
    printf("%s\n", _string);
}
```

Compiling and running reports:

```
$ clang -Wall -Weverything -g hello.c -o hello
$ ./hello 
Hello World!
```

Looks good, but then, if I try to profile memory using Valgrind, I get:

```
$ valgrind \
--track-origins=yes \
--leak-check=full \
--leak-resolution=high \
--num-callers=50 \
./hello

==31692== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31692== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31692== Using Valgrind-3.14.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31692== Command: ./hello
==31692== 
==31692== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==31692==    at 0x483ACC2: __strlen_sse2 (vg_replace_strmem.c:462)
==31692==    by 0x109177: main (hello.c:9)
==31692==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==31692==    at 0x109160: main (hello.c:7)
==31692== 
==31692== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==31692==    at 0x483ACD4: __strlen_sse2 (vg_replace_strmem.c:462)
==31692==    by 0x109177: main (hello.c:9)
==31692==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==31692==    at 0x109160: main (hello.c:7)
==31692== 
Hello World!
==31692== 
==31692== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31692==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==31692==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,025 bytes allocated
==31692== 
==31692== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==31692==    at 0x483777F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==31692==    by 0x109183: main (hello.c:9)
==31692== 
==31692== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31692==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==31692==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31692==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31692==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31692==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31692== 
==31692== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31692== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If I compile with optimization flags at -O3 level, I get green signal.

```
$ valgrind \
--track-origins=yes \
--leak-check=full \
--leak-resolution=high \
--num-callers=50 \
./hello
==32000== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32000== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32000== Using Valgrind-3.14.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32000== Command: ./hello
==32000== 
Hello World!
==32000== 
==32000== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32000==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32000==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==32000== 
==32000== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==32000== 
==32000== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==32000== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It looks like optimization fixes some of memory issues here. What's wrong with the code snippet? Which one is referred to "Use of uninitialised value"? myString? How can I initialize that?

**Edit:** As @Lundin advised, I have learnt the lesson not to assign strings with = directly. Thanks. Fixed code part =

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void callString(char *_string);
int main() 
{
    char *myString;
    myString = (char *)malloc(
    (unsigned long)strlen(myString)+1 * sizeof(char)
    );
    strncpy(myString, "Hello World", 11);
    callString(myString);

    free(myString);
    return 0;
}

static void 
callString(char *_string) 
{ 
    printf("%s\n", _string);
}
```

Thanks @Mat too

Comment: You're calling strlen on an unititalized pointer - undefined behavior. (Then throwing away the result of malloc anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 problems:

- `myString` is uninitialized so calling `strlen(myString)` doesn't make sense. You need to set it to something meaningful before calling `strlen`
- Your malloc call is wrong, you should not allocate `strlen(...) * sizeof(char)`, but rather `strlen(...) + 1`, since strings in C are null terminated and you must allocate room for the null terminator. Also, to multiply with `sizeof(char)` isn't necessary since that is guaranteed to be equal to `1`.
- After you malloc, you can't assign the pointer to something else: `myString = "Hello World!";`. This is what Valgrind complains about, it is a memory leak. Strings are copied using `strcpy`, not with `=` assignment.

Also, it is good practice to `free()` all memory at the end of the program.

Comment: I got the part strlen(...) + 1 right after this post, however what will be the best way to dynamically allocate memory for the string? strncpy?

Comment: Yes, you are right, ```strncpy(myString, "Hello World", 11);``` fixed the issue